# How can give third child div within one parent div

Tags: css, html

I have one Parent div. Top of the Parent div contains two child divs. How can i give third child div below the first child div

```
<div class=parent1>
  <div class=child1>some text</div> /*this is in top left of the parent div */
  <div class=child2>some text</div> /*this is in top right of the parent div */
  <div class=child3>some text</div> /*how can i write css for this div come as left bottom*/
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Can you post your html code here? The question isn't clear.

Comment: You have to show us what are these child1, child2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the css **float** will work if you are willing to assign a **fixed width** to your div's.

```
<style>
  div.parent1 {
    width: 800px;
  }

  .child1 {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
  }

  .child2 {
    float: right
    width: 400px;
  }

  .child3-container {
    clear:both;
    text-align: right;
  } 

</style>

<div class=parent1>
  <div class=child1>some text</div> 
  <div class=child2>some text</div> 
  <div class='child3-container' >
    <div class=child3>some text</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put jQuery to use to do the job easily. Use the **[`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** selector of jquery to get you the desired `div`:

```
$('div#parent div:eq(1)'); // gets second div inside a div with id parent
```

> How can i give third child div below
>   the first child div

If I get you, you want to add another div after the first child div, you can again use `eq` and `after` selector for that:

```
$('div#parent div:eq(0)').after('<div>Some Content</div>');
```

**Update:**

**[Here is the demo I created for that](http://jsbin.com/apiha)**

The idea is that parent div should be positioned `relative` and child divs `absolute` and then using `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` properties.

Comment: @rahul: It could be so but CSS is easy, one can simply add the class/id and style a particular elememnet but I think he is looking for how to add a child div just before first child div of a parent.